# How i can intercept web service in ibm broker?

Tags: integration

I do message flow in ibm message broker. SOAP Input -> SOAP Request -> Compute -> SOAP Reply.

I have WSDL file. In properties SOAP input and SOAP Request point it.
url: localhost:7800/sayHello

But does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should run in command line:

```
mqsireportproperties %BrokerName% -e %IntegrationServer% -o HTTPConnector -r
```

In output you can view port and URLRegistration of your service.